# Find the point(s) on the plane x+y-z=3 that are closest to the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know that the constraint over here is the plane, x+y-z=3, I also know that we have to minimize the distance. I'm just having a tough time starting to answer the question.

Comment: The square of the distance from the origin of a general point of your plane is the function:
$f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 + (x+y -3)^2$.

Comment: think about the Hessian Normalform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To minimize the distance is equivalent to minimize the square of the distance.

The square of the distance from the origin of a general point of your plane is the function:
$$f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 + (x+y -3)^2$$.

Therefore you just have to find the critical points (it's actually just one) and check that the hessian is negative-definite at that point.

EDIT: The minimum of the function should be at $(x, y) = (1,1)$, therefore the minimizing point of the plane is $(1,1,-1)$.

Comment: I actually found (1,1,-1) when I differentiated but was not sure if it is the answer.

Comment: Yes, it is correct! :)